# Extending map between curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider two integral curves $X,Y$ over an arbitrary base field $K$. Assume that $X$ is regular, $Y$ proper and there exists an open subset $U \subset X$ such that there exists a morphism $f_U: U \to Y$.

When and why can this map be extended to $f_X:X \to Y$ ? Is futhermore the condition that $X$ is regular necessary ?

Comment: Show that the graph of $f$ in $X\times Y$ maps isomorphically to $X$ by the first projection, using the fact that $X$ is regular. Yes, regularity of $X$ is necessary.

Comment: @Mohan: let's try: firstly I assume that by $f$ you refer to $f_U$? in this case by definition the graph is nothing but the image of $(id_U, f_U): U \to U \times Y$. using canonical inclusion $i:U \times Y \subset X \times Y$ we can see the graph of $f_U$ as a subscheme of $X \times Y$. denote by $pr_X: X \times Y \to X$ the projection. by definition the composition $pr_X \circ i \circ (id_U,f_U)$ is exactly the inclusion $U \subset X$.

Comment: therefore if we can show that the graph $Im(i \circ (id_U,f_U))$ is isomorphic to $X$ via projection $r_X$ then $pr_X^{-1}$ is the desired extension of $f_U$. but I don't know how to use regularity of $X$ to show that that the "graph" $Im(i \circ (id_U,f_U))$ is isomorphic to $X$ via the projection. could you help?

Comment: Take the graph and its closure in $Z\subset X|times Y$. Then the map $Z\to X$ is proper, since $Y$ is proper. It is also birational, since over $U$ it is an isomorphism. Thus the map $Z\to X$ is finite (proper morphism of curves) and birational, so $Z\to X$ is integral and birational,  but $X$ is normal, being regualr and thus the map is an isomorphism.

Comment: I think I understand... with the exception of the argument why the resulting map $Z \to X$ is finite. does birat and proper imply finite and (if yes) why?

Comment: No, proper and quasi-finite implies finite. Since the map is between irreducible curves and dominant, it is quasi-finite.

Comment: @Mohan: following argument still not satisfies me: why is $g:\overline{Im(id_U,f_U)}=Z \to X$ proper  if $Y$ proper? is $Z \to X$ nothing but the pullback of $Y \to Spec(K)$ along $X \to Spec(K)$ (if yes why?) or does here another argument it's job?

Comment: If $\pi:A\to B$ is a proper map and $C\subset A$ is closed, then the restriction of $\pi$ to $C\to B$ is proper.